# Selenium - get a number as a value

Tags: python, selenium

That is my code:

```py
chrome_driver_path = 'C:\Development\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
driver.get('https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')

button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#bigCookie')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

my_path = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[19]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]')
content = my_path.get_attribute('div')
print(content)
```

What I would like to do, is I would like to get a number shown in the picture below:[image]

Now I tried to get that number with the ".text" method but then I searched and realized that I cant use it because it's not an actual value. I tried to convert it into an int so that I can use it. I found the `get_attribute` method( shown in the linked code how I used it ), but no matter if I try to pass in as a value the span, div, id, or class name it returns none.

My question is how can I get that number( shown in the picture ) to get it as a value so that I can use it as an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was quite simple. I needed to wait before I would open what I wanted as this element that I wanted to select only appear when I have x amount of coin.

( Needed to use sleep )

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. You are looking on a wrong element
2. You have to improve locators
3. To get the element text you can to use `.text`
   Something like this will work better:

```py
the_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='productIconOff0']/..//span[@id='productPrice0']").text
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is that I am not looking to use .text as it doesn't give me the actual value. I cant use it as an int and therefore I cant use it in my program.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. So what value are you trying to get and how to use after that?

Comment: remove the comma and then convert to int?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Currently I don't understand what SO is trying to do here

Comment: I think that's what it is. Just .replace(",","") would be it.

Comment: I am trying to get the number as a value so that I can work with i. What I would like to do is to see if the price is lower than my cookies( my paying valuta ) then the "bot" should purchase the item. However I cant use the number as a value because of the comma. I tired to replace, and delete but some why it doesnt work and I dont understand why.

Comment: I figured out a method so I could get rid of the comma. I sliced it but I cant convert the end result into an int either.

When I am trying to convert it into an int this is the message I get:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''